# Get original request url in WCF REST service

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I've to retrieve the orginal request url in my WCF rest webservice. Now my code looks like this:

```
public class MyServiceAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        base.CheckAccessCore(operationContext);

        var url = operationContext.IncomingMessageProperties.Via.OriginalString;
        ...
```

web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
      <standardEndpoints> 
         <webHttpEndpoint>
             <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

if my original url is

**http://192.168.1.100:8081/test**

this code return

**http://hostname:8081/test**

is there a way to retrieve the exact original request url?

**Note**

I found posts talking about cutomize "baseAddress" tag in web.config but I've no specific endpoint fom my extensionles webservice and I don't want to add it. I don't know if there is a way to do it without endpoint.

I found this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915713/735864 plays with System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Host but with port number it doesn't works! I know I can parse provided url and do a Replace but... I don't think this is the best practice to achieve this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.OriginalString;
```

This gives the original URI.

Comment: One advantage of using WebOperationContext in contrast to HttpContext (referenced in another answer) is that it support a wider range of scenarios, including self-hosted services. HttpContext, on the other hand, is limited to aspNetCompatibilityMode and IIS hosting.

Comment: Actually, RequestURI will always give you the FQDN.  BaseURI will give you the domain name the browser actually submitted, which may not be the same.  In REST scenarios, however, BaseURI does not include the rest path beyond the base service route.

Comment: I would like to use this, but `System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch` is `null` ... what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Never mind ... `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To` gives me what I need.

Comment: karthik,@Hinek,everything that i tried here,return me servername.I mean url contain servername.it do not contain host url or ip

Comment: doesn't return the request url

Comment: When IIS starts running, I am getting the fqdn, site.domain.tld, but after running for a day or so, this suddenly switches to only the server hostname: Serv1. Nothing changed. No code changed. Site isn't under heavy load.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: `var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`

Long answer: See [How to get the URL of the current page in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp) .

**Warning: This only works if you enable [aspNetCompatibilityEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-services-and-aspnet#hosting-wcf-services-in-aspnet-compatibility-mode) in web.config file.**

Comment: I think `HttpContext.Current` is only accessible for WCF services which are running in ASP.NET compatibility mode.

Comment: Yes, HttpContext.Current is null unless you run it ASP.NET compatibility mode, as is noted by @JoshM.