# WCF 3.5 find the url the client used to get to the service (server side)

Tags: wcf

I am trying to find the url the client used to get to the server, (on the server side).  I have tried the following:

```
Uri url = OperationContext.Current.Channel.RemoteAddress.Uri;
Uri url = OperationContext.Current.Channel.Local.Uri;
Uri url = OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress.Uri;
```

but none of these seemed to work correctly.  They all return the server name, (with the fully qualifed domain. such as myserver.mydomain.local.  Even if I used used myserver/myservice.svc it would get the full name.

At this point I don't have a service and domain available to test going to mywebsite.com/myservice.svc to see if it has the machine name or not.

The result I want to get (from the server would be):

http://mywebsite.com/myservice.svc

rather than

http://myserver.mydomain.local/myservice.svc

which is what seems to be happening at the moment.

Comment: Jon. I have the same problem. Did this question has been solve?

Comment: Jon,@OammieR,how you solve the problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get original request url in WCF REST service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110397/get-original-request-url-in-wcf-rest-service)

Comment: @KumarHarsh - See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110397/get-original-request-url-in-wcf-rest-service

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `HttpContext` you can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

`OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.To`

Should give the Uri that client used to connect to the server.