# Get current endpoint on WCF Services?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, server-side, endpoint

I have a WCF service communicating with client over TCP. Is there anyway to gather information about the current connect in a service method? For example the endpoint that the current user is using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`OperationContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.current.aspx) property to get all kinds of useful information about the method you are currently in.

For your specific example:

[`OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.endpointdispatcher.endpointaddress.aspx)

Comment: Hi @Josh, can you please go through this link ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616995/wcf-3-5-find-the-url-the-client-used-to-get-to-the-service-server-side . can you reply it ?